# Trying the most basic JAVA code

Tags: java

I have installed Java SE and Eclipse on my system. I have tried to create a Java project Displayer with a class disp with the following code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class disp
{
    out.println("print");
}
```

But when I run the project, I am facing the following errors:

1. Syntax error on token ""print something"", delete this token
2. Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

How to fix it? Do I need some other file before I can run a project or what else should be done?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: where is main method?

Comment: you need a main method

Comment: You need to add methods to your class; the default entry point is "public static void main(String[] args) { .... }"

Answer (score 2):

1. In Java classes you cannot put executable statements outside functions or initializers. Printing is an executable statement, so it needs to go in a function.
2. More specifically, the function that you need must be called `main`. It needs to be `static`, return nothing (i.e. be of type `void`) and take `String[] args` or `String... args` as an argument.
3. It is more common to reference `out` as `System.out`, rather than statically importing it. This would let you avoid importing anything.

Here is a very basic template that you can use for your Java program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ... // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining as opposed to spitting out answer.

Answer (score 0):

try with these

```
     import static java.lang.System.out;
    public class disp
    {
    public static void main(String args[]){

      out.println("print");
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to

place out.println("print"); within main function 
OR
place out.println("print"); within some other function and then call it

Quick fix would be to place out.println within main function like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
      out.println("print");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

```
import java.io.*;
public class disp
{
public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println("print");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to make a simple "Hello World" program.

Few things to note:

Your statement is outside a method and isn't being used to assign anything, it needs to be in a method, in this case, the `main` method (first method java invokes).

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class disp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        out.println("print");
    }
}
```

The JVM finds the main method and begins execution at the start of the method and proceeds through the method sequentially executing statements in order.

If:

1. You don't have a main method, your java program doesn't know where to begin.
2. You put statements outside methods, they won't get executed and shows up as syntax errors (unless used to assign class/instance variable).

**P.S:** Unless you know what that `import static` is doing, you shouldn't really be using it, probably just confuses you more. Simply remove that line and change your:

```
out.println("print");
```

to

```
System.out.println("print");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've installed Eclipse and JRE to your system, open a new Java file, typed 3 lines of code and in the first error you encountered you came here and asked the question so people can tell you what's wrong instead of reading a couple of documents, or looking to the examples which you can find in Google easily. 
People are here are just going to answer your question, many of them are just trying to increase their reputation score -even including me- but that's not a real help to you. This is not a good way to learn programming. Trying to find your own mistakes makes the most crucial part of learning.